# .htaccess - masking long address into subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to hide long url address into sub-domain, while sub-domain and main domain redirects to same directory.

Currently, my both `domain.com` and `name.domain.com` redirects to `/var/www/domain.com`.

If user visits `name.domain.com`, I'm checking the address with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` , if user is in `name.domain.com`.
If he really is there, i'm redirecting him to `http://domain.com/index.php?user=name`. Just curious now, when user is visiting the site with long address, can I `mask` the address so it shows: `name.domain.com` only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php($|/) index.php?name=%2 [PT,L]`

Kinda resolved my problem, but if theres something that should work better, let me know, thanks!